# Angular TypeScript get item from a promise after invocation

Tags: angular

I am trying to solve an issue I have, but not sure how to do it.
I have a service with a method to get pages from **Contentful**, it looks like this:

```
async getPages(): Promise<Page[]> {
  const response = await this.cdaClient.getEntries({
    content_type: "page",
    include: 3
  });
  return response.items.map(this.createPage);
}
```

Which I invoke in my **app.component**:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  this.pages = await this.contentfulService.getPages();
}
```

What I would like to do, is when it's invoked, store it on the `contentfulService` so I can query it later. Something like this:

```
private pages: Page[];

getPage(slug: string) {
  return this.pages.find(page => page.slug === slug)
}

async getPages(): Promise<void> {
  const response = await this.cdaClient.getEntries({
    content_type: "page",
    include: 3
  });
  this.pages = response.items.map(this.createPage);
}
```

But the problem with that is that I would the getPage to be a promise also, so that I can call it from my route component:

```
page: any;

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private contentfulService: ContentfulService
) {}

async ngOnInit() {
  this.page = await this.contentfulService.getPage(this.router.url.split("#")[0]);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Why does `getPage` need to return a promise if it's not running asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wondering why you want a `Promise`, but the answer is this:

```
getPage(slug: string) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.pages.find(page => page.slug === slug));
}
```